# Is the difference between getting hit by an object connected or disconnected to the excerting source of force negligible?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

This article is facing with the impact of a single lightsaber in the mideavel time. And in the comments of this answer I was explaining that I would expect the disconnection from the blade by beeing cut from the sabber would increase the loss of force (no pun intended) to the lightsaber wielder.

https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/39561/3460

Many are stating that the lightsaber wouldn't be that usefull since cuting the allready traveling blade would not hinder it from hitting you with the same power.

While the main statement sounds legit to me aswell, I would assume that disconnecting the hitting object from the force excerting point would decrease the excertet force to the hit target by an non negligible amount.

Am I that wrong?
If so, why?

Answer (score 1):

If the blade of in 'incoming' metal sword is cut by the light saber, the tip would fly off in a straight line (and not follow the arc of the sword anymore). That straight line might still end in in your face or other body parts, but the damage done is only dependant on its weight and speed (its momentum) and no longer supported by the arm of the assailant.

You can imagine it as a knife being thrown at you - the sword tip behaves exactly like a voluntarily released knife thrown at you, just it will not fly as controlled as a trained knife-thrower would make it fly.

For RPG purposes, I would assume it as a thrown knife, with the equivalent damage.

Note that the cut-off sword stump might have some very sharp edges that can hurt too; and probably will hit if the sword would have hit.

Comment: So my mainasumption is right, and it might indeed have an not negigible impact?

Comment: If I throw a knife in your face, would you call that not neglible? Your decision. ;-)

Comment: I'm askign my self how the swordman should have tryed to hit me with his sword so the cut off projectile sets itself into my face like an thrown object. but note: Here I'm asking about the amount of force. So lets say a sword is swung against my leg or it is cut off before it hits my legg. the arguments over there are this doesn't  matter. I'd assume it would.

Answer (score 1):

The damage done would depend in part on the mass of the weapon.  Think of it like using a hammer.  You typically can't just push a nail into wood with a hammer unless you swing it.  As you swing the hammer you give it kinetic energy which is then used to do work driving in the nail (or bashing in a helmet).  Once the hammer hits the nail you are still typically applying some force on the hammer but only for quite a short time so this makes up a relatively small part of the hammers effect on the nail. Even if the hammer's shaft were to break before you hit the nail it will still apply quite a bit of force.

A light weapon, like a rapier or a dagger, doesn't have much mass and so doesn't acquire much kinetic energy as you swing it.  Its damage depends much more on the force you apply while it in in contact with the target.  A heavy weapon, like a mace or heavy sword, would be the opposite - more like the hammer described above.

As Aganju mentioned massive weapons tend to be swung in an arc before they hit but a cut off part would travel in a straight line rather than continuing in an arc which would would make it more likely to miss - no guarantees.

Comment: So here my request for clarification again: What ever of the both types is used (heavy or light) in both cases it isn't true that cutting the weapon would be not preventing more then a negigible part of the attack? I have to admit, I wasn't thinking of heavy weapons yet. Here I see the point that was made. but a weapon that is designed to cut of party of me would even if it is hitting me after the hitting part got disconnected be a lot less dangerous. Right?

Comment: Yes I agree, a _light_ weapon that got cut off by a light saber would be a lot less dangerous.